# Angular 1.6 component router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new in this. I have been searching and trying about how to route components in angular 1.6, but didn't find any satisfactory answer. There are some examples, but not complete. I want an example with syntax and which route file to import.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) as it is better than [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute). You can google for examples on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at ui-router it has implementation for routing to component. Check this link for more info: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component